# Replace <a> if it ends with a string JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find all anchor tags that have `href` attributes that end with some specific image extensions. I want to replace them by image tags.

I've tried the following, but it doesn't match any anchor:

```
var imageTypes = ["jpeg", "jpg", "gif", "png", "bmp", "tif"];
$(".tfeedpost-postcontent a").each(function () {
    var actualA = $(this);
    var actualHref = $(this).attr("href");
    if (actualHref.match(imageTypes)) {
      actualA.replaceWith("<img src='" + actualHref + "'>");
    }
});
```

And I've tried this too:

```
if (actualHref.match(imageTypes + "$")) {
      //...
}
```

If I put the following, it works, but obviously only with one type of image.

```
if (actualHref.match("jpg$")) {
      //...
}
```

How can I have a match for any of the extensions?

Comment: did any of the provided solutions answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the pipe operator (which functions as an OR in regular expressions), and demand that it is preceded with a dot and occurs at the end of the string ($):

```
 if (actualHref.match(/\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png|bmp|tif)$/)) {
     ....
 }
```

The following extension will also deal correctly with URLs that have arguments or hashes that look like image extensions

```
 if (actualHref.match(/^[^?#]*\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png|bmp|tif)($|[?#])/)) { ...
```

This expression requires that no "?" or "#" occurs before the matched extension, and allows one of them to appear right after it.

Comment: @thedarklord, thanks for pointing that out: now the extended version also works well with hashes. You might want to do something similar in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following will do what you want:

```
var imageTypes = ["jpeg", "jpg", "gif", "png", "bmp", "tif"];
$(".tfeedpost-postcontent a").each(function () {
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    var ext = url.split('#').shift().split("?").shift().split('.').pop();
    if ($.inArray(ext, imageTypes) > -1) {
      $(this).replaceWith("<img src='" + url + "'>");
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47mhj4vk/1/)

edit: updated to reflect the case mentioned by epascarello and trincot

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with the array of types, pull out the file type, and use indexOf to see if it is in the array

```
var fType = actualHref.split("/").pop().split(".")[1]
var isImg = imageTypes.indexOf(fType)>-1;
```

Ways this would fail, if there is a querystring on the end. You would be better off to use `.pathname` instead of `.href`